# Need to preview html entered in a form by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, forms

I'm working with some code and what I want to do is straightforward.  There is a form box for users to enter html into.  When the preview button is pressed, a preview of the page created by the html will be displayed, either in a new tab or in a pop up.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm working in .Net but can also use javascript.  Thanks

-Matt

Comment: So, where's your code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service and expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: I was just trying to get the basic functionality.  Here one sec.  Thanks

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Heading</h1>

<p>Paragraph.</p>

<textarea name="TextBox1" id="TextBox1" style="height:448px;width:865px;Z-index:104; LEFT: 104px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 176px">
</textarea> 

</body>
</html>

Comment: that didn't  come out well. One sec

Comment: Hey, I have figured out my problem.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how this will fit into your work but it will get you going.

```js
function renderHTML(){
  var html = document.getElementById("writtenHTML").value
  document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
#writtenHTML{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="writtenHTML"></textarea>
<button onclick="renderHTML()" type="button">Click Me!</button>

<div id="preview"></div>
```

Hope it helps!